# How to get all radio buttons inside a table?

Tags: javascript, radio-button

i have group of radio buttons inside a table along with other inputs in this table, and i can't get the radio buttons by id or name or by tag name, i want to get them by type if this possible, because id and name is auto generated by JSF, and i don't want to change this.

so the requirement is: get all radio buttons only (not all inputs) inside the table so i can loop on them.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('input')`. Check for the type of each element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope there's only one set of radio buttons. In that case something like this can help:

```
var inputs = yourForm.elements;
var radioes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
    if (inputs[i].type == 'radio') {
        radioes.push(input[i]);
    }
}​
```

In case there are more than one set of radio buttons, better approach would be to have a dictionary with the `name` as the key and the value as the array of radio buttons in the group.

Comment: how to put all those radio buttons in an array together.

Comment: Answered inline :). On a serious note, please consider using jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

I know the question doesn't mention [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), but I just wanted to demonstrate the simplicity of it; please consider this more of a selling point of "hey, look how nice jQuery is".

```
// look how pretty I am
var radioButtons = $('table#MyTableId input[type="radio"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your form name is `yourForm` ... (`<form name = "yourForm">`) ... an easy way is just to  parse  all form elements and check for the type, something like this:

```
var your_namespace = {};
your_namespace.your_function = function() {
    var l = document.yourForm.elements.length;
    for (i=0; i<l; i++) {
        var type = yourForm.elements[i].type;
        if (type=="radio") alert("Form element " + i + " is a radio!");
    }   
}
```

Instead of alerting you can ofc do alot of other things with the element id.

You can have this way easier when using a framework like MooTools or JQuery.